# How to find/replace complicated statements in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to do something that I believe is easy but I couldn't figure it out. I'm simply trying to find a section of code and replace it. I have a method in several files

```
    [TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof (InvalidOperationException))]
    public void RetrieveWithInvalidKey()
```

And I'm trying to replace it with:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void RetrieveWithInvalidKey()
```

I can't just find `[TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof (InvalidOperationException))]` because there are many others that I do not want to change. I only want to change the ones with the `public void RetrieveWithInvalidKey()` afterwards. I tried to find *[TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof (InvalidOperationException))]\npublic void RetrieveWithInvalidKey()* using regular expressions but it didn't find it.

How do I find this specific block of code for replacing? I also have ReSharper if that can do it but it didn't recognize a method pattern.

Comment: Regex is the way to go. What is the regex string that you were using?

Comment: @Maciej I used several. I tried `[TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof (InvalidOperationException))]\npublic void RetrieveWithInvalidKey()` with and without the spacing, as well as `[TestMethod, ExpectedException\(typeof \(InvalidOperationException\)\)]\npublic void RetrieveWithInvalidKey`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using regex in find box, you must escape the '[', ']', '(', and ')' characters with a backslash.

Thus you should use:

```
\[TestMethod, ExpectedException\(typeof \(InvalidOperationException\)\)\]\n:b*public void RetrieveWithInvalidKey\(\)
```

for your search.

Type in the following in the replace box:

```
[TestMethod]
public void RetrieveWithInvalidKey()
```

That should get you what you want.